# Can't create rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Can't create a rails project after installing rails.

Mac Mojave 10.14.6

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin18]

$ which ruby
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby

$ gem -v
3.1.2

$ sudo gem install rails

Successfully installed rails-6.0.2.2
Parsing documentation for rails-6.0.2.2
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Then tried to create a rails project

```
$ rails new blah
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.

$ which rails
/usr/bin/rails
```

Any ideas why I can't create a rails project as rails seems to be installed?

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.1 (2020-03-31 patchlevel 83) [x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/shanegibney/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/shanegibney/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
     - /Users/shanegibney/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /opt/local/bin
     - /opt/local/sbin
     - /opt/local/bin
     - /opt/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/mysql/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/TeX/texbin
     - /opt/X11/bin
     - /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
     - /opt/ImageMagick/bin
     - /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Then,

```
$ /usr/bin/rails new blah
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
-bash: tail: command not found
-bash: sed: command not found
```

Also tried,

```
$ export PATH="/usr/bin/rails" >> ~/.bash_profile 
-bash: tail: command not found
-bash: sed: command not found
```

Thanks,

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210962/discussion-on-question-by-shane-g-cant-create-rails-project).